# Binding method result to v-model with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How do you bind a method result to a v-model with Vue.js?

example :

```
<someTag v-model="method_name(data_attribute)"></someTag>
```

I can't make it work for some reason.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a computed value for this.

Comment: That doesn't work because I can't pass a parameter to a computed property, I want the model to be evaluated with the attribute I'm passing. Edit: I'll try splitting things into components

Comment: If you can post a less obfuscated example maybe we could be of more assistance. It's unclear to me why you'd do it like this.

Comment: @greenymaster69 did you able to sort this issue?

Comment: You could wrap the component within another component and pass the data_attributes as a prop and use the computed set/get strategy as explained below.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Years later, with more experience, I found out that is it easier to bind `:value` instead of using v-model. Then you can handle the update by catching `@change`.

Edit (per request):

```
<input :value="myValue" @change="updateMyValue">

...

methods: {
  updateMyValue (event) {
    myValue = event.target.value.trim() // Formatting example
  }
}
```

And in a child component:

```
// ChildComponent.vue

<template>
  <button
    v-for="i in [1,2,3]">
    @click="$emit('change', i) />
</template>

// ParentComponent.vue

<template>
  <child-component @change="updateMyValue" />
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from './child-component'

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  data () {
    return {
      myvalue: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateMyValue (newValue) {
      this.myvalue = newValue
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Always love to see people coming back to provide a valuable answer to their own question, very helpful!

Answer (score 42):

`v-model` expressions must have a `get` and `set` function.  For most variables this is pretty straight forward but you can also use a computed property to define them yourself like so:

```
data:function(){
    return { value: 5 }
},
computed: {
    doubleValue: {
        get(){
            //this function will determine what is displayed in the input
            return this.value*2;
        },
        set(newVal){
            //this function will run whenever the input changes
            this.value = newVal/2;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use `<input v-model="doubleValue"></input>`

if you just want the tag to display a method result, use `<tag>{{method_name(data_attribute)}}</tag>`

Answer (score 4):

Agree with the **:value** and **@change** combination `greenymaster`.
Even when we split the computed property in get/set, which is help, it seems very complicated to make it work if you require a parameter when you call for get().
My example is a medium sized dynamic object list, that populates a complex list of inputs, so:

- I can't put a watch easily on a child element, unless I watch the entire parent list with deep, but it would require more complex function to determine which of the innter props and/or lists changed and do what fromthere
- I can't use directly a method with v-model, since, it works for providing a 'get(param)' method (so to speak), but it does not have a 'set()' one
- And the splitting of a computed property, have the same problem but inverse, having a 'set()' but not a 'get(param)'