# Vue why is value in input -- respresented as empty string in v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hey I'm working on custom input component for integers only, with 2 modes based on `acceptNegatives` props, that indicates if it should accept the negative numbers or not, the problem is that my current implementation allows to add multiple `-` signs while the component should accept the negatives too.

What I'm trying to acomplish is to on prop `acceptNegatives="true"` the component should accept input or paste value like `-2` or `2` not `-0` or "--", "--2" because those values are treated as empty string for some reason.

Html of input component it uses default input from `Buefy`

```html
<template>
  <b-input
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :value="value"
    @input="handleChange"
    @paste.native="handlePaste"
    @keydown.native="handleKeyDown"
    @mousewheel.native="$event.preventDefault()"
    @blur="handleBlur"
    :icon-right="iconRight"
    :name="name"
    autocomplete="off"
    :type="type"
  ></b-input>
</template>
```

#### The JS part

- Keydown event handler

```js
handleKeyDown(event) {
      const { key } = event;
      if (this.acceptNegatives && this.isAdditionalKeyAllowed(event)) {
        this.$emit("keydown", key);
        return;
      }

      if (this.isAdditionalKeyAllowed(event) || this.isValidNumber(key)) {
        return this.allowPositiveNumbersOnly(event);
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    },
```

- Is additional key

```js
isAdditionalKeyAllowed(event) {
      const allowedKeyWithoutMeta = Object.values(ALLOWED_KEYS).includes(keyCode);

      if (this.hasAlreadyMinusSign(event.target.value, key)) {
        return false;
      }

      if (this.acceptNegatives) {
        return (
          allowedKeyWithoutMeta || key === "-"
        );
      }

      return allowedKeyWithoutMeta;
    },
```

- hasAleardyMinusSign fn to check if we already have minus sign, fails because - is treated as empty string

```js
hasAlreadyMinusSign(value, key) {
      return this.acceptNegatives && value.includes("-") && key === "-";
    },
```

I've prepared also little demo how it works in Vue. Currently I have no idea how to resolve this. Should I use watcher or the value should be computed value somehow? Thanks for advice.

https://codesandbox.io/s/integernumberinput-j4jlj?file=/src/components/IntegerNumberInput/IntegerNumberInput.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to strip the possibility of `'------1'`, the easiest way to do this is using some [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28673744/4826740):

```
inputVal() {
  // Regex that replaces all occurrences of "-" except the last
  return this.value.replace(/[-](?=.*[-])/g, "");
}
```

Then bind the input to this computed and use a [getter and setter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35211146/4826740), something like this:

```
inputVal() {
  get() {
    // Regex that replaces all occurrences of "-" except the last
    return this.value.replace(/[-](?=.*[-])/g, "");
  },
  set(val) {
    this.value = val;
  }
}
```

Or you could add the first snippet I've provided as a method that you call during some other validation process. That's up to you to decide